# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-simply-order-export/main.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Godaddy migrated my server and I have a site on wordpress / woocommerce that has the woocommerce-simply-order-export plugin. After the migration the site is generating this error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /fakepath/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-simply-order-export/main.php**

The problem is when I install the site on my local server (with the same code), the website runs without problem.

I have tried renaming the plugin so that the site does not use it, but the server does not generate any response when compiling being empty, without any line of code when compiling the HTML

Any help about what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have different versions of PHP. go to that file, and try replacing

```
$whatever = [];
```

with

```
$whatever = array();
```

`[]` notation for arrays isn't supported in older versions of PHP < 5.4

Also, if this is not the case, it could be that you need to deactivate/activate woocommerce as this plugin checks if Woocommerce is enabled.

From `woocommerce-simply-order-export/main.php`

```
if ( 
    in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) 
    && ( -1 !== version_compare( get_plugin_data( WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/woocommerce/woocommerce.php' )['Version'], '3.0.0' ) ) 
) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
My php version is 5.4, but I do not know how to activate / deactivate woocommerce to test what it tells me.

Comment: @IvanGil you just need to go to wp-admin -> Plugins and find Woocommerce on the list and activate it

Comment: Thanks again!.  the problem is that the error does not allow me to enter the admin ...